# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library on Ubuntu

Tags: dll, cron, ubuntu-14.04, php-extension, php-7.2

some background information:

Ubuntu 14.04 minimal and upgraded php from verion 5.x to 7.2

and now I get every 30 minutes an email from the **`cron daemon`** with the following subject:

`Cron <root@v52775>   [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi`

and following content:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_intl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_intl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mysqli.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

I'm a little bit confused because I don't know how i get this `.dll` files and not any `.so`.

I look at the php info, so the **intl** and **mysqli** module are active. The same information I get when I write `php -m` on my terminal.
But **not** the **mysql** extension! I disabled the older php version, only php 7.2 is running on my system.

The another confusing is the path. I'm not sure but in the e-mail from the cronjob ist the path `/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_*` but the php info shows me `20170718`. I put a screenshot here.

[screenshot php info extention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRYCi.png)

How I can fix it, I hope someone can help me?
Please ask me if you need more information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it!

I do `sudo apt-get remove "php*"` and install php once again. After that you get a email with a lot of warnings like that.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xml.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/xml.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/xml.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/xml.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

This can be easily fixed by installing the missing modules.